# AWS Cloudformation - nested stacks - stack keeps failing deploy but not reason is given

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront, nested-stack

I got a simple cloudformation stack made of only two nested stacks, one for the hosting and serving of a single page application web app and the other for the authentication logic (for now it only define a Cognito user pool resource).
The auth nested stack keeps failing during deployment, but I can't figure out why as not reasonable motivation is given by the command.

I still get the error even after manually deleting the entire stack hierarchy and creating a new one.

After the aborted operation I'm left with the main stack and two empty nested stacks, each one in the `DELETE_COMPLETE` status.

Running `sam validate` on the nested stack template gives no error:

```
> sam validate --template-file nested-stacks/auth.yaml 
2023-01-16 12:15:01 Loading policies from IAM...
2023-01-16 12:15:04 Finished loading policies from IAM.
/media/sgratani/Data/tests/AWS/serverless spa/aws_stack/nested-stacks/auth.yaml is a valid SAM Template
```

#### nested stack template

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'


Description: >
  - A Cognito user pool


Parameters: {}


Resources:
  UserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties: 
      AccountRecoverySetting:
          RecoveryMechanisms: 
            - Name: verified_email

      AdminCreateUserConfig: 
        AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: true
        InviteMessageTemplate: 
          EmailMessage: Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}.
          EmailSubject: Your temporary password
        UnusedAccountValidityDays: 30

      # AliasAttributes: 
      #   - String
      # AutoVerifiedAttributes: 
      #   - String
      EmailConfiguration: 
        EmailSendingAccount: COGNITO_DEFAULT
      MfaConfiguration: OFF
      Policies: 
        PasswordPolicy: 
          MinimumLength: 8
          RequireLowercase: true
          RequireNumbers: true
          RequireSymbols: true
          RequireUppercase: true
          TemporaryPasswordValidityDays: 7
      # Schema: 
      #   - SchemaAttribute
      # UsernameAttributes: 
      #   - String
      UsernameConfiguration: 
        CaseSensitive: true

      VerificationMessageTemplate: 
        DefaultEmailOption: String
        EmailMessage: Your verification code is {####}.
        # EmailMessageByLink: String
        EmailSubject: Your verification code
        # EmailSubjectByLink: String
```

#### `sam build` output deployment section

```
Initiating deployment
=====================
File with same data already exists at 0320ec2e303c20d5454978a63234f9ed.template, skipping upload

Waiting for changeset to be created..
CloudFormation stack changeset
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation                                LogicalResourceId                        ResourceType                             Replacement                            
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Add                                    AppHosting                               AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               N/A                                    
+ Add                                    Auth                                     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               N/A                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Changeset created successfully. arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:575288510223:changeSet/samcli-deploy1673867103/a08f41d4-6786-4039-8916-ab73a37a0d1e


2023-01-16 12:05:15 - Waiting for stack create/update to complete

CloudFormation events from stack operations (refresh every 0.5 seconds)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceStatus                           ResourceType                             LogicalResourceId                        ResourceStatusReason                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                       AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               Auth                                     -                                      
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                       AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               AppHosting                               -                                      
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                       AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               Auth                                     Resource creation Initiated            
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                       AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               AppHosting                               Resource creation Initiated            
CREATE_FAILED                            AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               Auth                                     Embedded stack                         
                                                                                                                           arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-             
                                                                                                                           central-1:575288510223:stack/test-spa- 
                                                                                                                           Auth-IB3AC3208DMY/aa040170-958d-11ed-9 
                                                                                                                           c56-0a7beb596806 was not successfully  
                                                                                                                           created: The following resource(s)     
                                                                                                                           failed to create: [UserPool].          
CREATE_FAILED                            AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               AppHosting                               Resource creation cancelled            
ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS                     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               test-spa                                 The following resource(s) failed to    
                                                                                                                           create: [Auth, AppHosting]. Rollback   
                                                                                                                           requested by user.                     
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS                       AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               AppHosting                               -                                      
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS                       AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               Auth                                     -                                      
DELETE_COMPLETE                          AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               Auth                                     -                                      
DELETE_COMPLETE                          AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               AppHosting                               -                                      
ROLLBACK_COMPLETE                        AWS::CloudFormation::Stack               test-spa                                 -                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Failed to create/update the stack: test-spa, Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
```

#### final nested stacks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the nested stack template actually had a few errors in it, a test deployment on its own pointed them out as being the main stack lead to a more clear output from `sam deploy` command.

BTW, don't understand why `sam validate` didn't alert me, since one of the errors were actually a value type error, eg 'Integer' string instead of an actual integer (copy/paste from docs without updating, my fault).

This had me thinking: what do actually `sam validate` validates?